# htaccess Redirect https for specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, directory

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Redirect all WWW requests to equivalent (without WWW)
- Redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP
- Redirect all requests to subdirectory /cart to force HTTPS

Here is what I have but it's giving me a loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(cart/.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

#www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]

#https to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]

#if the request is for /cart then enable https 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cart
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```